# Can't disable auto debug

Tags: android

In the meantime of programming my app, it occurred, that even if i push the "run" button in eclipse (not the Debug one) the application starts in debug mode. Even if i pull out the Usb cable and start the app manually over the phone menu, it "waits for the debugger to attach"...

After deinstalling and reinstalling the manual start works well (w/o debugger) until I get an error. Afterwards always the debugger connects...

Can anyone explain me whats going on in "eclipses" or "androids" head here?
THX!

Comment: I has also same problem. Restart your Android device that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Use the perspective DDMS , and run your app, and then , you will see the icon of debugging in the process of your app , uncheck it and it will work ;

if id didn't work , open the perspective Debug ,then, disable all the breakpoints , and it will work
"

or maybe you can try to delete the current run/debug cofiguration from eclipse proprties. Take a look on this

Comment: Thx for your answer. where i could change or delete the debug configuration i dont know.. in the DDMS window i cant find any debugging icon, can you give me a hint? But disabling all breakpoints works, not the most comfortable method, but works :) thx

Comment: Deleting the run configuration and creating a new one (with same settings) worked for me. You do that from the dropdown menu on the "run" button > Run configurations > right click > delete/new configuration. Don't forget to specify the name for the configuration and also the project.

Answer (score 1):

Tried a lot way on this but nothing works.
But I just fixed this by terminating the process with 8600 port through DDMS process list in devices view.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Tried all the above and had no solution.  I found my fix. Click on the Debug perspective button.  Once it's selected, right click on it and then select 'reset'.  This stopped the debugger from being called even when I was selecting "Run" and not "debug".

On further evaluation.. The following fixed my problem.  The issue seems to be in the phone and not Eclipse.. this is a rare problem.  I only found a hand full of people with same issue.

1) Uninstall app. 
2) Hard reboot phone. 
3) Reinstall app.

Now, eclipse won't go into debug mode even when all the preferences are set correctly and you select 'Run' and not 'debug'.

Comment: Okay, I think I actually have found a fix.  The problem seems to be in the handset itself.  1)Uninstall application.  2) Hard reboot the phone 3) Reinstall application.  This worked for me. I edited original post.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem . **Simply delete the app on the phone and reinstall it. Restart the device**. It works for me.

I tried different ways without results:

- delete all breakpoints.
- restart Eclipse, DDMS